# Negative mass as a property of space-time

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass, dark-energy

What if negative mass is a property of space-time itself? We know that dark energy works against gravity and is currently expanding universe, while this expansion is increasing. Can this be because the hypothesized negative mass repels the positive mass, which causes a repulsive gravitational force.  Please give your opinion about this idea and criticism is welcomed.

Comment: Hi, please refrain from posting "blue-sky" personal theories here.  That's not the intended usage of physics.SE

Answer (score 2):

In general relativity, the thing that produces gravitation (spacetime curvature) is stress energy tensor, not just mass. This also includes pressure, so negative pressure can cause expansion.

Dark energy is modeled quite nicely with positive cosmological constant. This can be interpreted as negative pressure of vacuum, but if one computes this pressure from quantum field theory, one gets number that is 120 orders of magnitude bigger than measured value for cosmological constant.

So the idea is entertained, but so far it leads to no explanation.